# Second series solution to Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find a series solution about the point $x=0$ for $\gamma\ne0$ of the
>   differential equation $x^2y''-xy'+(1-\gamma x)y=0$ and write down the
>   form of a second independent solution.

So far I have identified $x=0$ as a regular singular point and so multipled through by $x$ to obtain an equidimenisonal equation. Let $y=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_nx^{n+\sigma}$ and eventually arrived at $a_n=\frac{\gamma}{n^2}a_{n-1}$ and so $y=a_0(1+\frac{\gamma}{1^2}x+\frac{\gamma^2}{1^22^2}x^2+...+\frac{\gamma^n}{(n!)^2}x^n+...)$.

Firstly I would ask if there is any way to simplify this sum, I don't recognise it and I can't see how to evaluate the series.

Secondly, I don't know how to easily find the second solution, the wording 'write down' suggests that no additional working is required, I had a similar problem on an earlier question with finding a second solution, so this is the more important one to be answered.

Thank you.

Comment: I feel like your recurrence should be second order; after all, this is a second order equation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Change first $x=\frac z\gamma$ which makes $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\gamma\frac{dy}{dz}\qquad , \qquad\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\gamma^2\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}$$ and the equation becomes $$z^2\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}-z\frac{dy}{dz}+(1-z)y=0$$ Now, have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) and look at the given example .... which is this last equation. The problem of the second solution is explained in the *Z-separate roots* paragraph.